# watin capture popup window and click "Yes"

Tags: .net, popup, watin

I use watin to log into a website and retrieve information. If there is another login already exist for the same account in somewhere else, the website popup a window and say "close other sessions?" and there are two buttons "Yes" and "No". I need to capture this and click "Yes".

I don't know what type of the popup is, I tried AlertDialogHandler and ConfirmDialogHandler, but seems not working, could anyone help?? below is the code sniplet. Thanks!

```
   BrowserIe.Ie.Image(Find.ByName("login")).ClickNoWait();

    AlertDialogHandler d= new AlertDialogHandler();
    if(d.Exists())
    {
        log.Debug("got alert dialog when logging in...");
        d.OKButton.Click();
    }

    ConfirmDialogHandler confirm = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
    if(confirm.Exists())
    {
        {
            log.Debug("got confirm dialog when logging in...");
           confirm.OKButton.Click();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
ConfirmDialogHandler confirm = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(BrowserIe.DialogWatcher, confirm))
{
    BrowserIe.Image(Find.ByName("login")).ClickNoWait();
    confirm.WaitUntilExists();
    confirm.OKButton.Click();
}
```

Depending on the speed of the message, you may not even need the Wait method.

Another way to skin this same cat is to override the JavaScript confirm function, returning true:

```
BrowserIe.RunScript("function confirm(message) { return true; }");
```

Comment: Seems this will work. In my case, the confirmation popup is NOT always popup, sometime yes, sometime no. So I use: if(confirm.exit()).... could you be more specific on how to overrite the javascript confirm funtion? I don't have the code of the website. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The examples I've seen have all looked more like this: -

```
ConfirmDialogHandler confirm = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
using (UseDialogOnce udo = new UseDialogOnce(BrowserIe.DialogWatcher, confirm))
{
    dlgHnd.WaitUntilExists();
    confirm.OKButton.Click();
}
```